# Device orientation not work properly in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, orientation, landscape-portrait

```
+(CGFloat)maxTextWidth
{
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
           {
        return 220.0f;
           }
           else
           {
               return 400.0f;
           }
    }
    else
    {
        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
        {
        return 400.0f;
        }
    else
    {
        return 700.0f;
    }
    }
}
```

when my device in portrait orientation according to the above method it return the portrait value but the problem is that in portrait orientation sometimes it return the portrait value and sometimes it return landscape value but my device always in portrait orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your if statement check status bar orientation instead of device orientation..

```
+(CGFloat)maxTextWidth
{
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
           {
        return 220.0f;
           }
           else
           {
               return 400.0f;
           }
    }
    else
    {
        if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
        return 400.0f;
        }
    else
    {
        return 700.0f;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Helped me, As UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait issue with iOS 11.

Answer (score 1):

Copy this code in your viewdidload.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didrotatedevice:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and copy this method in your class

```
- (void)didrotatedevice:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];


    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
          NSLog(@"Landscape Left!");

    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
         NSLog(@"Landscape Right!");

    }
    else
    {
          NSLog(@"Potrait!");

    }
  }
```

Let me know if you have any doubts?

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn’t use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Or you can use this

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Or this

```
-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

These methods detect any orientation changes.
Set your UI changes in these methods.

Comment: I work on chatting so that i return the max text width according to device orientation so that i use a class method and above code work same as your code....